# Rails - How to a validate model being altered in before filter from a different model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Models - Purchaseorder, Purchaseorderadjustments, Productvariant, Location, Locationinventory

I'm storing inventory in Locationinventory which stores a location_id, productvariant_id, and quantity.

The situation arises when I want to create a purchaseorder. I'm using purchaseorderadjustments as a nested attribute to the purchaseorder. A purchaseorder has_many purchaseorderadjustments that store the productvariant_id and quantity.

I'm using before filters to create,update and destroy the related locationinventory records. Everything works well as it is now except that you can remove items from a location that doesn't have them available and the quantity just goes into the negative. I want to verify that the "From Location" has enough of the productvariant in stock to transfer to the "To Location".

Am I doing it wrong? thanks!

Rails 3.2.14

**Purchaseorder.rb**

```
class Purchaseorder < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :fromlocation_id, :status_id, :tolocation_id, :user_id, :purchaseorderadjustments_attributes

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :status
  belongs_to :fromlocation, :class_name => "Location", :foreign_key => :fromlocation_id
  belongs_to :tolocation, :class_name => "Location", :foreign_key => :tolocation_id
  has_many :purchaseorderadjustments, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :purchaseorderadjustments, allow_destroy: true

end
```

**Purchaseorderadjustment.rb**

```
class Purchaseorderadjustment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :adjustmenttype_id, :productvariant_id, :purchaseorder_id, :quantity

  belongs_to :purchaseorder
  belongs_to :productvariant
  belongs_to :adjustmenttype

  validates_presence_of :quantity, :message => "You need a quantity for each product."

  # On creation of a purchaseorderadjustment go ahead and create the record for locationinventory
  before_create :create_locationinventory
  def create_locationinventory
    # Get some info before updating the locationinventory
    if fromlocationinventory = Locationinventory.find(:first, conditions: { :location_id => purchaseorder.fromlocation_id, :productvariant_id => productvariant_id })
      fromlocation_current_quantity = fromlocationinventory.quantity
    end
    if tolocationinventory = Locationinventory.find(:first, conditions: { :location_id => purchaseorder.tolocation_id, :productvariant_id => productvariant_id })
      tolocation_current_quantity = tolocationinventory.quantity
    end

    # Create or update the from locationinventory
    unless fromlocationinventory.nil?
      fromlocationinventory.quantity = fromlocation_current_quantity - quantity
      fromlocationinventory.save
    else
      new_fromlocationinventory = Locationinventory.new({ location_id: purchaseorder.fromlocation_id, productvariant_id: productvariant_id, quantity: 0 - quantity })
      new_fromlocationinventory.save
    end

    # Create or update the to locationinventory
    unless tolocationinventory.nil?
      tolocationinventory.quantity = tolocation_current_quantity + quantity
      tolocationinventory.save
    else
      new_tolocationinventory = Locationinventory.new({ location_id: purchaseorder.tolocation_id, productvariant_id: productvariant_id, quantity: quantity })
      new_tolocationinventory.save
    end

  end

  #On update of purchaseorderadjustment
  before_update :update_locationinventory
  def update_locationinventory
    # Get some info before updating the locationinventory
    fromlocationinventory = Locationinventory.find(:first, conditions: { :location_id => purchaseorder.fromlocation_id, :productvariant_id => productvariant_id })
    tolocationinventory = Locationinventory.find(:first, conditions: { :location_id => purchaseorder.tolocation_id, :productvariant_id => productvariant_id })
    fromlocation_current_quantity = fromlocationinventory.quantity
    tolocation_current_quantity = tolocationinventory.quantity

    fromlocationinventory.quantity = fromlocation_current_quantity - quantity + self.quantity_was
    fromlocationinventory.save

    tolocationinventory.quantity = tolocation_current_quantity + quantity - self.quantity_was
    tolocationinventory.save

  end

  #On destroy of purchaseorderadjustment
  before_destroy :destroy_locationinventory
  def destroy_locationinventory
    # Get some info before updating the locationinventory
    fromlocationinventory = Locationinventory.find(:first, conditions: { :location_id => purchaseorder.fromlocation_id, :productvariant_id => productvariant_id })
    tolocationinventory = Locationinventory.find(:first, conditions: { :location_id => purchaseorder.tolocation_id, :productvariant_id => productvariant_id })
    fromlocation_current_quantity = fromlocationinventory.quantity
    tolocation_current_quantity = tolocationinventory.quantity

    fromlocationinventory.quantity = fromlocation_current_quantity + quantity
    fromlocationinventory.save

    tolocationinventory.quantity = tolocation_current_quantity - quantity
    tolocationinventory.save

  end

end
```

**productvariant.rb**

```
class Productvariant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :barcode, :compare_at_price, :fulfillment_service, :grams, 
                  :inventory_management, :inventory_policy, :inventory_quantity, 
                  :option1, :option2, :option3, :position, :price, :product_id, 
                  :requires_shipping, :shopify_id, :sku, :taxable, :title, :shopify_product_id, :product_title

  belongs_to :product, primary_key: "shopify_id", foreign_key: "shopify_product_id"
  has_many :purchaseorderadjustments
  has_many :locationinventories

  def product_plus_variant
    "#{self.product.title} - #{self.title}"
  end
end
```

**locationinventory.rb**

```
class Locationinventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :location_id, :productvariant_id, :quantity

  belongs_to :productvariant
  belongs_to :location

end
```

Comment: Wow lots of custom methods!

Answer (score 1):

I'll write this answer because I feel you've provided so much code, you might have scared some answerers away!

Our experience is as follows:

---

**Nested**

You can validate nested models in several different ways

Your question is related to passing data in a `accepts_nested_attributes_for` - you can validate this directly:

```
#app/models/purchase.rb
Class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :purchase_items
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :purchase_items
end

#app/models/purchase_item.rb
Class PurchaseItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :purchase

    validates :name,
          presence: { message: "Your Purchase Needs Items!" } #Returns to initial form with this error
end
```

---

**Standard**

If you want to [conditionally validate](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation) based on another model, you'll have to use [`inverse_of:`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) to keep the object available throughout the data transaction:

```
#app/models/purchase.rb
Class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :purchase_items, inverse_of: :purchase
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :purchase_items
end

#app/models/purchase_item.rb
Class PurchaseItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :purchase, inverse_of: :purchase_items

    validates :name,
          presence: { message: "Your Purchase Needs Items!" },
          if: :paid_with_card?

    private
    def paid_with_card?
        self.purchase.payment_method == "card"
    end

end
```

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for taking the time! I know I included a lot of code. I did it to illustrate how I was doing the CRUD for the Locationinventory model. You can see that it's all happening in before filters in the purchaseorderadjustments model and not really through a relationship per-say. So I'm not sure if you're answer is saying that I should change how that works or if you didn't notice how it's being done. I've no ego about this stuff and am a forever student so please say if I'm doing it wrong. :-) thanks!